# Using StreamedResponse for a rest api endpoint in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to do something like the following where I have a rest api endpoint - and I'd like to return a streamed response. However, when I try this in Wordpress it seems to get an error on the new StreamedResponse() call. Best I can tell with the debugger it never seems to call the callback function I have setup.
Has anyone done this in a custom Wordpress plugin and got it working?
Thanks.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

...

function bootstrap(): void {
  add_action( 'rest_api_init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\register_chatbot' );
...
function register_chatbot(): void {
  // Add route for POST to 'gsb-chatbot/v1/conversation' endpoint.
  register_rest_route(
    'gsb-chatbot/v1', '/conversation', array(
      'methods'             => 'POST',
      'callback'            => __NAMESPACE__ . '\\gsb_conversation_callback',
      'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
    )
  );
}
function gsb_conversation_callback($request) {
...
  return new StreamedResponse(function () use ($stream) {
    $fullText = '';
    foreach ($stream as $response) {
      if ($response->choices[0] != NULL) {
        ...
        $json_string = json_encode($response_obj);
        echo $json_string . "\n";
        ob_flush();
        flush();
      }
    }
  }, 200, [
    'Content-Type' => 'text/event-stream',
  ]);
```